# Are triangles rigid in 4 dimensions?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, rigid-transformation

I have read in a couple of sources that a graph with n vertices is rigid in d dimensions if and only if its rigidity matroid has rank n*d - d*(d+1)/2.  C3 (a triangle graph) has a rigidity matroid of rank 3 for all dimensions greater than 1 (3 is an upper bound, because the rigidity matrix only has 3 rows, and this bound is already realized for d = 2).

Since 3 > 3*d-d*(d+1)/2 for d > 3, this suggests that C3 becomes flexible in 4 and higher dimensions.  However, since C3 is a complete graph, the distances between vertices cannot change, so it should be rigid for all d.

Can someone clear up this conundrum?

Comment: Is there not an understanding that $d$ represents the dimension of the space spanned by vectors determined by vertex-points in a realization of the graph? After all, you can throw a triangle into any $d$-dimensional ambient space you like, but it's still a *planar* figure. (In general, a realization of a graph on $n$ vertices "uses" no more than $d=n-1$ dimensions.) "Non-planar" stresses/loads/whatever on the figure can move the vertices around in the ambient space, but the vertices will effectively *take their plane with them*, and those stresses can be modeled as if the plane didn't move.

Comment: In other words, you can only use the rank of the rigidity matroid to determine degrees of freedom if d<n.  That sounds reasonable.  But what if you are interested in how the degrees of freedom of a graph changes as d is increased?  For example, I have wondered how one might determine when a graph is rigid in R^n for all sufficiently large n (as is true of complete graphs).

Comment: "In other words, you can only use the rank of the rigidity matroid to determine degrees of freedom if d<n." Correct. Another example: for $n=4$, two triangles with a common edge. In $R^2$, the figure is rigid; in $R^3$, the common edge acts as a hinge: not rigid. In $R^{\geq 4}$, still the only possible flexing comes from the hinge action, so you might as well still be in $R^3$. I can't really speak to much beyond this; I saw a few lectures on rigidity matroids many years ago, but that's it. Perhaps someone with actual expertise in this area will stop by and provide you with more guidance.

Comment: I thought about your example of two triangles with a shared edge.  I think that the "hinge" will actually have 2 degrees of freedom in R4.  Why?  If you fix one of the triangles, then the remaining vertex must be a fixed distance from two of the vertices on that triangle.  Therefore, that vertex is only constrained to lie on the intersection of 2 3-spheres, which I believe is a 2 dimensional surface (a 2-sphere?).  Which is all just to say, the number of degrees of freedom does continue to change as d is increased even in this relatively simple case.

Comment: @AriHerman In $\mathbb{R}^4$, we can describe any configuration of the hinge as the angle between the two triangles, along with a rotation of the 3D hyperplane containing the hinge.  The latter is a Euclidean transformation so we can disregard it when considering rigidity.  So there's still only 1 degree of freedom in terms of deformation, even in 4+ dimensions.

Comment: A simpler example: Two segments sharing a vertex; take the vertices on the $x$-axis at $x=-1$ (fixed), $x=0$ (the shared vertex; fixed), $x=1$ ("free"). In $R^1$: rigid; in $R^2$: not rigid; the free vertex traces a circle in the $xy$-plane. In $R^3$: the free vertex gains a *geometric* degree of freedom, tracing an entire sphere; however, "rigidity" only notices the angle between the segments. For instance, each point in "equator" traced in the $yz$ plane creates a right angle; so far as rigidity is concerned, these are equivalent deformations. $R^3$ shows us nothing we hadn't seen in $R^2$.

Comment: @augurar Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Blue A nice example of this same idea.

Comment: This leads me to tentatively conjecture the following: Let G be a graph. Let d be the least positive integer such that G has a generic realization in R^d. Then if G has k degrees of freedom in R^d, G will have k degrees of freedom in R^e for all e>d.  Since all (finite) graphs have generic realizations in 3 dimensions, d = 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: All graphs have generic realization in $\mathbb{R}$ (just take an algebraically independent set to be the vertices) and so $d=1$ always. For a counter-example take $K_4 -e$ (complete graph on 4 vertices minus an edge) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $K_4-e$ is rigid but not rigid in $\mathbb{R}^3$, thus the degrees of freedom must change. @AriHerman

Answer (score 1):

I know I am *severely* late to the party but I will crack on regardless.

For a graph $G$ with placement map $p :V(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ let us define $k$ to be the dimension of the affine span of $\{p(v) : v \in V(G)\}$, $1 \leq k \leq d$. The correct formula for rigidity is $(G,p)$ is (infinitesimally) rigid if and only if its corresponding rigidity matrix has rank $$ d|V(G)| - \frac{(k+1)(2d+k)}{2}.$$ This is as the right part corresponds to the dimension of the infinitesimal isometries restricted to $p$. Assuming you choose your placement in general position then for $K_k$ ($k \leq d+1$) this equation satisfies.

Comment: Can you define $V(G)$ and $n$? Also, does $|V(G)|$ indicate the cardinality of $V(G)$?

Comment: @NBCKLY $V(G)$ is the vertex set of the graph $G$ and $|V(G)|$ is the size of $V(G)$ (I am assuming $G$ is a finite simple graph). Using $n$ was a typo, should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you have a reference for this expression? In particular, the dimension of the infinitesimal isometries of $p$ plays a vital role; do you have a reference for why it has cardinality $(k+1)(2d+k)/2$?

Comment: @NBCKLY The result is Lemma 2.3.3 in *Combinatorial rigidity* by Graver, Servatius and Servatius. The book is also a good reference for the area of geometric rigidity theory as a whole if you are interested in it.